# How to achieve parallax effect with Greensock?

Tags: jquery, gsap

### **Achievement**

I saw this smooth parallax animation of the hero video on [Antoni.de](https://antoni.de/career/). I notice two things here. First the scroll is smoothed out and secondly, there is a parallax effect inside the header video. I would like to achieve those effects.

**My code**
I came up with the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
            console.log(scrollPos);

            root.parallaxBackground(scrollPos);
        });
parallaxBackground: function(scrollPos) {

    // Development
    console.log('init parallaxBackground');

    // Still need work
    var background = $('.hero').find('.background');
    var simpleParallax = -.15;

    if (scrollPos > 0) {
        // Do the magic
        TweenMax.set(background, {
            x: 0, 
            y: -(scrollPos * simpleParallax)
        });
    }

}
```

### Problems

Above code is working, but when I go to fast, the background div will stuck at a certain amount of pixels when scrolling all the way to the top. ScrollPos should be zero so for the parallax too.

The question is what I doing wrong, or missing and what am I missing to get the smooth scroll in my experiment?

If there are any questions left or something, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you scroll too fast your variable scrollPos will jump from, let's say 300 to 0, therefore the code in your if condition will not be fired. What you need to do is to set scrollTop to 0 when that happens.

Something like this would work:

```
parallaxBackground: function(scrollPos) {

// Development
console.log('init parallaxBackground');

// Still need work
var background = $('.hero').find('.background');
var simpleParallax = -.15;
var pos = scrollPos;
if(scrollPos <= 0) pos = 0;
// Do the magic
TweenMax.set(background, {
    x: 0, 
    y: -(pos * simpleParallax)
});

}
```